# Reconnect remote origin

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm a bit lost with a git repo I'm working on currently deployed on Heroku

I pulled the repo directly from Heroku and began working, however I have since learned there is also an "origin" copy on GitHub

I am looking to "reconnect" with the github repo so I can push to it as well as Heroku.

My fingers are a bit nervous since I've found a couple of posts, one command that could look useful is:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO
```

But I'm not sure if that is supposed to push to origin for the first time, or to an existing repo?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO
```

does not push at all. It simply tells your local repository that you've got a remote named `origin` that can be found at `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO`. This command may be run at any time, either on a brand new repository or on one that you've been working on for years.

You can have many remotes, and in fact with Heroku you should have at least one more. Perhaps the other one will be called `heroku`.

Then you can do things like

```
# Push new commits up to GitHub ("origin")
git push origin master

# Push a new release to Heroku
git push heroku master
```

Just like there's nothing magical about the name `master` (it's just the default branch name that Git creates) there's nothing magical about the name `origin`. You could call it `github` if that makes more sense for you.

You may want to review or configure what the *default* push target will be, i.e. what happens if you simply `git push`? This depends on the version of Git that you are using as well as on your local configuration. If you tell us your Git version we can help with that too.